# get selected item from recyclerview on alert dialog , and display it into edittext

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I just create a dialog with a recycle view on it. Then how to get value from selected recycle view and set it into editext on the same acticity

[this is the dialog and the value from recycle view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvbN9.jpg)

[and this is the value will be set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbBYS.jpg)

My code for calling the dialog, and set addOnItemTouchListener for recycle view. And when i run it my application get force close

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@OnClick(R.id.button_choose)
void chooseLOV() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lov_kodepos, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rv_lov_kodepos);


    API.getKodePos().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<KodePos>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<KodePos>> call, Response<ArrayList<KodePos>> response) {
            if (response.code()== 200){
                Log.i("bella", "onResponse: "+response);

                data = response.body();
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(AddCustomerActivity.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(AddCustomerActivity.this));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new KodePosAdapter(data));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<KodePos>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(AddCustomerActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(AddCustomerActivity.this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddCustomerActivity.this,AddCustomerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DATA_KODEPOS, tempDatas.get(position).getPoscodeId());
            startActivity(intent);

            if(dataKodePos.getPoscodeId()==DATA_KODEPOS){
                API.setKodePos(getIntent().getStringExtra(DATA_KODEPOS)).enqueue(new Callback<KodePos>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<KodePos> call, Response<KodePos> response) {
                        KodePos hehe = response.body();
                        et_provinsi.setText(hehe.getPosProp());
                        et_kota.setText(hehe.getPosKota());
                        et_kecamatan.setText(hehe.getPosCamat());
                        et_kelurahan.setText(hehe.getPosLurah());
                        et_kodepos.setText(hehe.getPosKode());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<KodePos> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }else {

            }

        }

    }));
```

My Adapter

```
 public class KodePosAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<KodePosAdapter.KodePosViewHolder> {

ArrayList<KodePos> datasSet;

public KodePosAdapter(ArrayList<KodePos> data) {
    this.datasSet = data;
}

@Override
public KodePosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.lov_recyclerview, parent, false);

    return new KodePosViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(KodePosViewHolder holder, int position) {
    KodePos kdModel = datasSet.get(position);

    holder.kodePos.setText(kdModel.getPosKode());
    holder.kecamatan.setText(kdModel.getPosCamat().toLowerCase());
    holder.kelurahan.setText(kdModel.getPosLurah().toLowerCase());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datasSet.size();
}

public class KodePosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView kodePos, kecamatan, kelurahan;

    public KodePosViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        kodePos = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_lov_kodepos);
        kecamatan = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_lov_kecamatan);
        kelurahan = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_lov_kelurahan);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use `getAdapterPosition()` in adapter to get the index of clicked item and so is data .

Comment: where should i place the get adapter position ? @ADM

Comment: can you post the code of `KodePosAdapter`

Comment: yes , i've edit it @VishalYadav

Comment: in your `onBindViewHolder`  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                
            }
        });`

Comment: yes i've did it, but then i confused to set to the edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, implement KodePosViewHolder with `OnClickListener`

```
public class KodePosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Override `onClick` and get the position of the item clicked

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        }
```

from this `adapterPosition` get the `kdModel` then get the text and show it in Alert dialog.

```
KodePos kdModel = datasSet.get(adapterPosition);
```

Comment: i'll try it @Shylendra Madda

Comment: but i want to show it to edittext in the actvity not in alert dialog. and the value in the edittext is get from alert dialog

Comment: may i have your email sir ? @Shylendra Madda

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you need to create an **OnItemClickListener** and set it to your recyclerView adapter in order to get the clicked item data.

Secondly,create a similar **OnRecyclerItemClickListener** to your dialog.In this case,you need to create a **CustomAlertDialog** class that extends AlertDiaglog.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem. It is much simple than I thought. After i click the item i only have to display the value in edit text with this way

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(AddCustomerActivity.this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            et_kodepos.setText(data.get(position).getPosKode());
            et_kota.setText(data.get(position).getPosKota());
            et_provinsi.setText(data.get(position).getPosProp());
            et_kecamatan.setText(data.get(position).getPosCamat());
            et_kelurahan.setText(data.get(position).getPosLurah());
        }
    }));
```